# How do I make a div which spans 100% the width of the page and using with a two colour background?

Tags: html, css

Please excuse me if this question has been answered before, but I couldn't find an answer when searching.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to create a header bar which is 107px high and spans 100% width of the page with a split in colour 50% (50% the left is white, 50% on the right is green) along its width. I have been able to accomplish this using CSS gradients, however I work in the education sector and schools seem to be reluctant to use anything but legacy versions of IE and so, inevitably, it doesn't work properly.

Is there anyway to do this which is IE friendly or is there any kind of work around that can give me the same or similar results?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does there have to be a gradient?

Comment: how about an image as the background, make it so that it is wide enough to cover most screen sizes the use the 50% 50% position and repeat-y

Comment: The image is a good fallback from using MS gradient syntax.

Comment: Try Adam's answer and check it

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of options:

1. Use a background image (5px high, really wide, left half is white, right half is green) - it'll cost you less than 100 bytes.
2. Why not use two divs (floated left, both 50% width)?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div style="background: white;">
        white bg
    </div>
    <div style="background: green;">
        green bg
    </div> 
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
.header { overflow: hidden; height: 107px; border: 1px solid #000;}
.header div { float: left; width: 50%; height: 100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PUWCh/

Comment: That is not what he asked at all.

Comment: Why 5px heigh? 1px will suffice ;)

Comment: That's exactly what he is asking for, also this will work in legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2gGdD/

I'm using pseudo selectors (works back to IE8) to create each half and layer them behind the div with a negative z-index so you can place content on top of them.

```
.header {
    height: 107px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.header:before,
.header:after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.header:before {
    background: red;
    left: 0;
}
.header:after {
    background: blue;
    right: 0;
}
```